# Retrieving Values from Custom Settings based on 2 field combination and how to retrieve in trigger

Tags: trigger, customsetting

I have 4 fields on my custom setting

1. record type name,
2. record type id
3. status
4. send email
5. notification type

Now i have to create a new record based on the case status and status combination like
[image: RecordTypeName SobjectType Status RecordtypeId Send Email]

Currently problem is when i am creating a case record for record type R1 with open status it is creating 3 new record for open status .same for waiting it is creating 2 and for closed it is creating one record . it is not matching with record type name and status.

i want to create one record for R1-open i Send_Email_to_email__c want this to consider R2 status. Also Send_Email_to_email__c is getting checked in all the condition

```
trigger NewtestcaseRecord on Case(after inseRecTY, after update) {
    Map < string,
    string > caseRecordTypeMap = new Map < string, string > ();
    set < string > caserectype__c = new set < string > ();

    List < Case > casel = new List < Case > ();
    string rec_type;
    RecordClass RectyCS = new RecordtypeCSClass();
    RectyCS.CaseFetchrectype__c();

    Map < string, Custom_Setting__c > allRecordTypeMap = RecordtypeCSClass.CaseRecordtypeMap; //Get all Custom setting records
    system.debug('allRecordTypeMap :NewServicenetrecord:' + allRecordTypeMap);
    for (Custom_Setting__c RecTY: allRecordTypeMap.values()) {
        for (Case c1: trigger.new) {
            if (RecTY.RecordTypeId__c == c1.RecordTypeId && RecTY.Status__c == c1.Status) {
                string status = RecTY.Status__c;
                system.debug('status' + status);
                system.debug('RecTY.RecordtypeName__c' + RecTY.RecordtypeName__c);
                caseRecordTypeMap.put(RecTY.Name, RecTY.RecordtypeId__c.substring(0, 15));
                caserectype__cet.add(RecTY.RecordtypeId__c.substring(0, 15));
                rec_type = c1.RecordTypeId;
                system.debug('rectyoe' + rec_type);
                if (caserectype__cet.contains(rec_type.substring(0, 15)) && c1.AD_Private__c != true) {
                    System.debug('Condition satisfied');
                    // if (c1.Status == status )                      {
                    system.debug('Statis' + c1.Status);
                    system.debug('Statis' + status);
                    casel.add(c1);
                    system.debug('casel' + casel);
                    system.debug('casel size' + casel.size());
                    // }
                    //}
                }
            }
        }

        //  }// for loop
        system.debug('caseRecordTypeMap : ' + caseRecordTypeMap);
        system.debug('caserectype__cet : ' + caserectype__cet);

        List < test_Case__c > testcaseList = new List < test_Case__c > ();
        if (!casel.isempty()) {
            for (case c: casel) {
                rec_type = c.RecordTypeId;
                Custom_Setting__c CRecTY = new Custom_Setting__c();
                test_Case__c testcase = new test_Case__c();
                testcase.Case__c = c.ID;
                testcase.Send_Email__c = true;

                if (caserectype__cet.contains(rec_type.substring(0, 15))) {
                    if (c.Status == RecTY.Status__c) {
                        testcase.Notification_Type__c = RecTY.Notification_Type__c;
                        system.debug('test Notification' + testcase.Notification_Type__c);
                    }

                    if (RecTY.Send_Email_to_email__c = true) {
                        testcase.Send_Email_to_email__c = true;
                    } else {
                        testcase.Send_Email_to_email__c = false;
                    }
                }

                if (testcase.Notification_Type__c != null && testcase.Notification_Type__c != '') {
                    testcaseList.add(testcase);
                }
            }
        }

        Chatter_helper.setIstestcaseCreated();
        system.debug('**in inseRecTY testcaseList.size()' + testcaseList.size());
        if (testcaseList.size() > 0) {
            inseRecTY testcaseList;
        }
        system.debug('inseRecTY testcaseList :' + testcaseList);
    }
}
```

Comment: Inconsistent indentation and brace style can make it difficult for others (and you!) to follow your code. I've used a formatter to try to clean up the code style.

Comment: I have rolled back an edit to this question to undo destruction of the content. Please do not erase question content.

Comment: Divya, if you continue to destroy question content I will lock this post. Please do not do this.

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating all the custom settings values, which also has inner for loop for all the cases inserted/updated . It's something like-

```
for(Custom_Setting__c RecTY : allRecordTypeMap.values()){
        for(Case c1:trigger.new){

         if(RecTY.RecordTypeId__c == c1.RecordTypeId && RecTY.Status__c == c1.Status){           
       casel.add(c1);
             }
        }
    }
```

So when you create a case let's say with record type R1 and Status as -Open ,then condition

```
if(RecTY.RecordTypeId__c == c1.RecordTypeId && RecTY.Status__c == c1.Status)
```

will be true 3 times based on the custom settings above, as you have outer 'for loop' iterating over all the records of the custom settings and you are adding c1 to case1, 3 times. Similarly for other statuses as well.
**Instead of List of cases as Case1 , you can have set of cases as Case1 and before adding any new case c1 to case1 , you can check if that case already exists (based on record id), if it doesn't then only add c1 to Case1.**
Though I am not clear on what you want to achieve, but using set will avoid creation of duplicate records. Also, I see lot of scope of improvement in your code. You can avoid nested for loop, using map etc

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. by using set i can reslove this but .cantains method is not supporting in my code Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void contains(String) from the type Set<Case> at line 43 column 37 if(caselist1.contains(rec_type.substring(0,15))){
                       case1.add(c1);   }

Comment: Did you mean contains method in the set in not working as expected? Can you paste where and how are you using it?